# php variable as the column name in mysql_fetch_assoc variable

Tags: php, mysql

The following code shows error :  Undefined index: $col_name in ...

```
$table="my_table";
$col_name="my_col";

$sql="SELECT * FROM $table";

$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['$col_name']));

}
```

But if I replace the last line inside the while loop with the following one :

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['my_col']));
```

it's all ok.

How can I use a php variable as the column name instead of using the column name directly ?

Comment: why do you really need that ? `my_table` has a column `my_col` - isn't that enough ?

Comment: What about `$row[$col_name]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `double quotes`,

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row["$col_name"]));
```

Or here you can simply avoid quotes,

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row[$col_name]));
```

Read [***Strings***](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) for more about quotes.

Answer (score 1):

in the line

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row['$col_name']));
```

I think the `'string'` does not allow variable interpolation. In otherwords PHP won't interpret `$col_name` as a variable. Try

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row["$col_name"]));
```

Note the `''` is now `""`. Using `""` will interpolate variables in the string

EDIT:

"String interpolation" is where PHP parses the string, looks for variables, and replaces the variable with its string representation. Only happens when using double quotes.

E.g.

```
$var = 1234;
printf("$var\n");
printf('$var\n');
```

Would output

```
1234
$var
```

The first line because of string interpolation. The second line because no string interpolation is done with single quotes.

Comment: variable interpolation ?

Comment: PHP parses the string and looks for variables and replaces them in the string with the string representation of their value :) Edited post.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to surround with quotes `'` your variable `$col_name`, simply change to this

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row[$col_name]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to remove the ' as it isn't needed when you are using a PHP variable.

Change the line to:

```
$db_value = trim(htmlspecialchars_decode($row[$col_name]));
```

This will work for you.